# Circuit design using only NANDs and Inverters

Tags: nand

So I'm having trouble with some circuit design for class.
We're given a truth table with 4 inputs and 2 outputs. I have karnaugh maps for the inputs and simplified my boolean expression. We have to design the circuit using only NANDs and INVs. For some reason I'm just completley lost on this one. 
[image][image]

Comment: You got X and Y correctly.. why are you ANDing them ?

Comment: Take deMorgans of AND - OR and you get NAND - NAND.

Answer (score 1):

You have done a great job working out the independent output equations:

$$\begin{align*}
X &= D\:\overline{C}+B\:\overline{A}\\
Y &= C + B\:\overline{A}
\end{align*}$$

You need to apply a NAND as the final stage for each, right? I assume you already know de Morgan's two laws, cold. Right?

So just look at your two equations. They are both in sum of products form. Just double-NOT them and see where that takes you:

$$\begin{align*}
X &= \overline{\overline{D\:\overline{C}+B\:\overline{A}}}&&=\overline{\overline{D\:\overline{C}}\cdot\overline{B\:\overline{A}}}\\
Y &= \overline{\overline{C + B\:\overline{A}}}&&=\overline{\overline{C} \cdot \overline{B\:\overline{A}}}
\end{align*}$$

Well, there is definitely something useful there:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQx72u.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That pretty much gives it all away. Can you now proceed to complete the answer?

---

Enough time has gone by (about a full day since asked.) I might as well complete this for others who may come upon this and want to learn from it.

From the above, it's obvious now that:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFj0So.png)</sup>

Looks like two inverters and four NANDs.